# Count numbers and display a alert dialog

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a timer here

How do I create a jscript to count from 1 to 60 and to use alert when I've reached 30 using *for loop* and *while loop* method

Comment: Sounds like a home task. Moreover, sounds like an easy hometask. Try to do this yourself, and when you stumble upon problems or questions - try to find an answer in the Internet. If there is no answer in the Internet - come back here.

Comment: ahahahaha but everybody wants points .. kkkkkk @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: timers are cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both answers are count from 0 to 59.
Op want to count from 1 to 60

So,

```
 for(i=1; i<=60;i++)
      if(i==30) alert(i);
 i=1;
 while(i<=60){
      if(i==30) alert(30);
      i++;
 }
```

Comment: you should close the brackets of while

Comment: Thanks. Its a typo

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
for( var i = 1;i<=60;i++)
  {
    if(i == 30){
      alert("value is:"+i);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// using for loop
for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) { 
    if (i === 30) {
       alert('reached 30');
    }
}

// using while loop
var c=0
while (c < 60) {
    if (c === 30) {
       alert('reached 30');
    }
    c++;
}
```